# Test file to XML file (Problem with the structure)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, text-files, stax

I want to convert a text file to XML file with a specific structure. I want to separate the text into paragraphs and these paragraphs will get into a chapter. For example, every chapter should have 3 paragraphs. The root element of XML is called "Book".

To give you one more example, I have this text file:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a.
>
> Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam.

I want an XML which includes a chapter with these 3 paragraphs.

Here is my code:

**Chapter class:**

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Chapter {

    private String paragraph;
    private List<String> sentence;
    private List<String> words;
```

My main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String textInputFile = "xml_files/sample.txt";
    String xmlFileOutput = "xml_files/sample.xml";

    try (FileOutputStream outXML = new FileOutputStream(xmlFileOutput))  {
        Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(new File(textInputFile));
        convertToXml(inputfile, outXML);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}

private static void  convertToXml(Scanner inputfile, FileOutputStream outXML) throws XMLStreamException {
    XMLOutputFactory output = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = output.createXMLStreamWriter(outXML);
    writer.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");
    writer.writeCharacters("\n");
    // <books>
    writer.writeStartElement("book");
    // <book>
    while (inputfile.hasNext()){
        String line = inputfile.nextLine();
        Chapter chapter = getChapter(line);
        writer.writeCharacters("\n\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Chapter");
        writer.writeCharacters("\n\t\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Paragraph");
        writer.writeCharacters(chapter.getParagraph()+"");
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeCharacters("\n\t\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Sentence");
        writer.writeCharacters(chapter.getSentence()+"");
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeCharacters("\n\t");
        writer.writeEndElement();
    }
    writer.writeCharacters("\n");
    writer.writeEndElement();
    writer.writeEndDocument();
}

private static Chapter getChapter(String line){
    String[] paragraphs = line.split("\\r?\\n");
    String[] sentences = line.split("(?<=(?<![A-Z])\\.)");
    Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
    chapter.setParagraph(List.of(paragraphs));
    chapter.setSentence(List.of(sentences));
    return chapter;
}
```

I'm counting the sentences of each paragraph in the above code, but I don't have any problem there.

My output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<book>

<Chapter Paragraph="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.">
<Paragraph> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</Paragraph>
<Sentence>[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.]
</Chapter>

   <Chapter Paragraph="" Sentences="[]">
        <Paragraph/>
        <Sentences>[]</Sentences>
    </Chapter>

<Chapter Paragraph="Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a.">
<Paragraph> Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a.</Paragraph>
<Sentence>[Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat , Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate, Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a.]
</Chapter>

  (...)        

</book>
```

In the second chapter you can see I have null values inside paragraph and sentence. How can I prevent to print these nulls (I have a chapter with values and the next chapter is always null)? My second question is how can I have many paragraphs in one chapter? For example, I want every chapter to includes 3 paragraphs. Imagine that I have a text file with 10000 lines and I want to structure it into an XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: please notice that in your input, you have "empty lines"/linebreaks in your Lorem Ipsum. `Scanner.nextLine()` reports/provides these lines too. In order to avoid adding `Chapter`s for these which then result in an empty `<Sentences/>` in the output, what about adding

```java
if (line.isEmpty() == true) {
    continue;
}
```

to your loop after the `inputfile.nextLine()`?

Second question: what about something like

```java
private static void convertToXml(Scanner inputfile, FileOutputStream outXML) throws XMLStreamException {
    List<Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

    {
        Chapter chapter = null;

        while (inputfile.hasNext()) {
            String line = inputfile.nextLine();

            if (line.isEmpty() == true) {
                continue;
            }

            String[] sentences = line.split("(?<=(?<![A-Z])\\.)");

            if (chapter == null) {
                chapter = new Chapter();
            }

            chapter.getParagraph().add(line);
            chapter.getSentence().addAll(List.of(sentences));

            if (chapter.getParagraph().size() >= 3) {
                chapters.add(chapter);
                chapter = null;
            }
        }

        if (chapter != null) {
            chapters.add(chapter);
        }
    }

    XMLOutputFactory output = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = output.createXMLStreamWriter(outXML);
    writer.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");
    writer.writeCharacters("\n");
    writer.writeStartElement("book");
    writer.writeCharacters("\n");

    for (Chapter chapter : chapters) {
        writer.writeCharacters("\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Chapter");
        writer.writeCharacters("\n");

        for (String paragraph : chapter.getParagraph()) {
            writer.writeCharacters("\t\t");
            writer.writeStartElement("Paragraph");
            writer.writeCharacters(paragraph);
            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.writeCharacters("\n");
        }

        writer.writeCharacters("\t\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Sentence");
        writer.writeCharacters(chapter.getSentence()+"");
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeCharacters("\n\t");
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeCharacters("\n");
    }

    writer.writeCharacters("\n");
    writer.writeEndElement();
    writer.writeEndDocument();
}
```

with a Chapter.java like

```java
public class Chapter {

    private List<String> paragraph = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getParagraph() {
        return paragraph;
    }

    public List<String> getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }
}
```

and the `getChapter()` not needed (or you may put the plaintext file reading and XML output generation into separate methods, etc.)?

Please be aware, with my proposal, you keep all the `Chapter` objects and paragraph strings in memory. If you want to avoid this, you can mingle input file processing and output generation back together. I just separated the two for better illustration of how to arrange the collection of paragraphs. You could easily write out a `Chapter` once it has collected 3 paragraphs + at the end of the loop (in case there's a remaining `Chapter` object not written out yet), and not grow a `List<Chapter>`.